# NSUserDefaults returning (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm a newcomer to `NSUserDefaults` and am struggling to get my head around something I imagine is probably straightforward for most reading this.

I'm trying to retrieve a mutable array of strings if it exists in `NSUserDefaults` with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *globalAppsArray;

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"globalAppsArray"] != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Array found. Contents: %@", globalAppsArray);        
}
else
{
    globalAppsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}
```

After adding any new data to it I then want to save it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:globalAppsArray forKey:@"globalAppsArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When I relaunch the app, the mutable array is found OK but the contents are `null`.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your code once,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *globalAppsArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"globalAppsArray"] mutableCopy];
if(globalAppsArray)
    NSLog(@"Array found. Contents: %@", globalAppsArray);
else
    globalAppsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: [objectForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDJDJG) will return an immutable NSArray. Shouldn't you make a `mutableCopy`?

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much, Sunny. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows.

Comment: @JohnSauer: Thanks. How would I do that?

Comment: `[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"globalAppsArray"] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 4):

It should be something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *globalAppsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"globalAppsArray"];

if(globalAppsArray != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Array found. Contents: %@", globalAppsArray);
}
else
{
    globalAppsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}
```

Comment: [objectForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDJDJG) will return an immutable NSArray. Shouldn't you make a `mutableCopy`?

Comment: Yes, either that, or use NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: initializer.

Comment: Thanks. I've already accepted Sunny's answer but yours does the trick as well so have an up vote. =)